# How to release allocated memory/CPUs after each pyspark job in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: memory, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am using pyspark in Jupyter Notebook. 
When I am running jobs on Hadoop Cluster Jupyter Notebook is not releasing allocated memory and CPUs usage after finished jobs. Uses all available resources in the cluster and keeps them until I kill my session.

Comment: Anyone? Any help/advice would be helpful.

Comment: I posted this issue in the jupyter notebook github space
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4131

Comment: Great! Maybe there someone can help us :)